# Cannot pass state to action creator in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Here is the form

```
<PostBody>
  <Input value={this.state.title} onChange={(value) => this.onChangeTitle(value)} ref="titleInput" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" />
  <TextArea value={this.state.body} onChange={(value) => this.onChangeBody(value)} ref="bodyInput" id="body" name="body" placeholder="Post Content" />
  <ToolBar>
    <Button disabled={!this.props.ptitle || !this.props.pbody} onClick={this.props.doSave(this.state)}>Save</Button>
    <BackLink to="/posts">Cancel</BackLink>
    <div style={{float:'left', marginTop:'10px'}}>
      {backBtn}
    </div>
  </ToolBar>
</PostBody>
```

Here is how I call the action creator function

```
doSave: (state) => {
   dispatch(savePostAction(state));
},
```

But this results in the error

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing
>   state transition (such as within `render` or another component's
>   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved
>   to `componentWillMount`.

and is hitting infinite times resulting in

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I even tried calling another function on click and then calling the doSave() by passing the state from that function. Still getting the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Your variant You call function without click, when component is rendering.
Change `onClick={this.props.doSave(this.state)}` to `onClick={() => this.props.doSave(this.state)}`

Answer (score 1):

Reason is, `onClick` expect a `function`, you don't need to call that `function`, it will get called on click of button.

```
onClick={this.props.doSave(this.state)}
```

Here `doSave` will get called on each rendering without click.

So instead of:

```
onClick={this.props.doSave(this.state)}
```

Use:

```
onClick={() => this.props.doSave(this.state)}
```